# VPN Tunnel stuck in Connecting state when using iOS vpn configurations

Tags: ios, networking, vpn, tunnel, networkextension

I am trying to start a VPN packet tunnel using network extensions but the vpn always gets stuck in the "Connecting" state. However, personal VPN does connect using these same settings. After calling startVPNtunnel, the PackTunnel extension functions get called but the status still remains as Connecting

```
// Hard code VPN configurations
let tunnelBundleId = "group.linkapp.PacketTunnel"
let host = "hide.me"
let serverAddress = "free-ca.hide.me"
let username = "wahwah"
let password = "123456"

var vpnManager: NETunnelProviderManager = NETunnelProviderManager()

private func initVPNTunnelProviderManager() {
    NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences { (savedManagers: [NETunnelProviderManager]?, error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        if let savedManagers = savedManagers {
            if savedManagers.count > 0 {
                self.vpnManager = savedManagers[0]
            }
        }

        self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error:Error?) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }

            let providerProtocol = NETunnelProviderProtocol()


            Keychain.set(self.username, value: self.password)
            let passwordRef = Keychain.persistentRef(self.username)
            if passwordRef == nil {
                print("Failed to query password persistent ref")
            }
            providerProtocol.username = self.username
            providerProtocol.passwordReference = passwordRef
            providerProtocol.serverAddress = self.serverAddress

            self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = providerProtocol
            self.vpnManager.localizedDescription = "NEPacketTunnelVPNDemoConfig"
            self.vpnManager.isEnabled = true


            if self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration?.proxySettings == nil {
                self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration?.proxySettings = NEProxySettings()
            }

            self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error:Error?) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    print("Save successfully")
                }
            })

        })
    }
}


@IBAction func connectAction(_ sender: Any) {

    print("Go!")

    self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences { (error:Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        if ((sender as AnyObject).title(for: .normal) == "Connect") {
            do {
                try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        } else {
            self.vpnManager.connection.stopVPNTunnel()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by " personal VPN does connect using these same settings"

In the case if you stuck in Connecting state. There are two most likely possibilities:

1) You Network extension doesn't call a completion handler on

```
- (void)startTunnelWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))completionHandler
```

Completion handler let OS know that tunnel is up

2) Your app isn't subscribed to `NSNotification.Name.NEVPNStatusDidChange.`. As result VPN is started, but the app side doesn't know about it